# quality of food or food quality?

Tags: grammar, word-order

Which one is better?

> 1. Visitors picked up **food quality** as the prominent advantage of the island.
> 2. Visitors picked up **quality of food** as the prominent advantage of the island.

I know that "**food quality**" is a well-known collocation, but I wonder if it is ok to use "**quality of food**" or not?

Comment: Visitors to the island noted the quality of food as etc. Don't much like prominent advantage. You mean obvious, right?

Comment: 'Food quality' sounds to me like something an inspector would check up on. You obviously mean _good_ quality, so I would say something like 'the excellent quality of the food'.